# Add 1 to number inside of text string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have the following variable in JavaScript:

```
var variable = "a=1; b=2; c=14;"
```

How can I change `b=2` to `b=3`, `b=4345` to `b=4346`, so adding 1 to the number after `b=`?

Comment: is this a school task? Where would you use this syntax?

Comment: You'd need to parse this string, possibly with a regex, then update the value.  Out of curiosity, why do you have a string in this format?

Comment: @user12345789101112131415161718: You shouldn't store such information in a string is what Rocket wants to tell. Why do you need a *string*?

Comment: @Bergi I've got a table cell, with a string like this in it. I want to add 1 to a, b or c when the user clicks a button. I also have a function to move the cell content to another cell, so I can't use something thats add a var to the cell content. That's why I am using a string to change the content. (if I understand you good)

Comment: Why is my question voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var variable = "a=1; b=2; c=14;"

function incB(str) {
  var re = /(.*b=)(\d+)(.*)/, // split the string to the whole match and 3 groups
      a = re.exec(str); // <- ["a=1; b=2; c=14;", "a=1; b=", "2", "; c=14;"]
  return a[1] + (parseInt(a[2], 10)+1) + a[3];
}

variable = incB(variable); // <- variable will be "a=1; b=3; c=14;"
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit messy but you can easily utilize the .split() function. Here's an example :

```
var num = "a=1; b=2;";
var indSection = num.split(";");
var b = indSection[1].split("=");
document.write(++b[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function twice - first to separate those letters with their values and second time on those separated parts to separate letter from value. After that you can add 1 to each number and build the string again by concatenating all those parts.

You can also use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Could use a regular expression to parse the value out, and replace the original string with the new value, something like this:

```
var variable = "a=1; b=2; c=14;"
var reg = /b=([0-9])+/;
var i = parseInt(reg.exec(variable)[1]);

i++;

variable = variable.replace(reg, "b="+i);
console.log(variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
variable = variable.replace(/(b=)(\d+)(?=;)/g, function(_, pref, num) {
    return pref + (+num + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am against writting code, so here are some hints:

1. remove all whitespaces `str = str.replace(/\s/g,"");`
2. create an array `arr = str.split(";");`
3. loop on all elements of the array `for(i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++)`
4. assing `tmp` to `arr[i].split("=")[1]` Note: `[1]` takes the right part, `[0]` the left part
5. change `tmp` type from string to number with `tmp = tmp*1`
6. update `arr[i]` with `arr[i]=arr[i].split("=")[0]+""+(tmp+1)`
7. join `arr.join(" ;")` to create your string again

It seems you only want to change `b=`, so <del>inside the loop, make an `if` check on the left part and test it against `"b"`, however</del> it would be easier to split by `;b=` or `; b=`, then take the right part, then split it by `;` and take the left part, etc, etc. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21864409/908879).

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string on 'b=' and the first following semicolon, use parseInt() on b and glue it all back together.

```
var splitted = variable.split('b=');
var begin = splitted[0];                   //everything up to b=
var end = splitted[1];                     //everything from b= on
var b = parseInt(end.substr(0, end.indexOf(';')))+1;   //b+1
variable = begin+"b="+b+end.substr(end.indexOf(';'));
```